# How often do IME users use the Esc key, and should the Esc key discard changes?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, typing, multi-language

Let's say that a web page has a click-to-edit text field. Clicking it would convert the displayed text to a text field with a blue outline, and allow the user to start editing the text. Editing would end and the changes would be saved if the user clicks away (blurs the field), or presses Enter.

An English-language user will not normally press the ESC key when typing, and so I would normally bind the ESC key to cause editing to end and cause changes to be discarded.

However, it occurred to me that for some languages, like Japanese, the user may use the browser's IME editor. This would mean that a keystroke causes a menu of symbols to appear, and the user can press the ESC key to abort selection of a symbol.

The risk would be that if an IME user accidentally presses ESC more than once, it will abort and discard all of the changes. This could be especially painful if the user has typed multiple lines of text into a multi-line text field.

Since I only know English, I'm not sure how common it is for IME users to press the ESC key.

Should I avoid binding the ESC key to abort and discard changes? Obviously, I would not abort if they only press the ESC key once to clear the symbol they are currently choosing in the IME editor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you'll get this type of data unless there is some keystroke capture application running on a lot of computers while the IME editor is running.

For any destruction actions, the fail safe option is to allow user confirmation on the action rather than to simply hope that it is not something that the user is likely to do. There may be other reasons why even someone using English language settings might press the ESC key more than once.

Again, because this is a potentially destructive action, you probably don't want to make assumptions about what a user might or might not do (at least without analytics data or extensive testing), so you should just create a fail safe option and then you won't have to worry about this being an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that someone that regularly uses the IME editor could provide some insight into their use of the Esc key, just as I as an English typer can easily provide the feedback that the Esc key is rarely used during regular editing. I am leaning towards Esc = abort/clear for single-line editing, but to ignore Esc during multi-line editing. However, it could be that Esc is pressed so often by IME users that this behavior would be annoying even when editing a short text field.